# Increase the size of back and next buttons in p:wizard

Tags: primefaces

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<p:wizard id="ss"    
widgetVar="mywiz"  
flowListener="#{userWizard1.onFlowProcess}" 
style="font-size: 20px;">
</p:wizard
```

It's not working for the button, only for messages.

Comment: Hey mate, cleaned up your question with the correct formatting. Can you explain your problem a little more?

Comment: What is the problem using CSS? Look at the client-side html and be creative

Comment: i just want to increase size of back and next button of wizard without customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many options is to manually add primefaces button into wizard component.

Example:

.xhtml file

```
<p:wizard flowListener="#{testBean.onFlowProcess}"
                  id="wizard"
                  showNavBar="false"
                  showStepStatus="false" 
                  widgetVar="wizardVar">
     <p:tab ...>
          ...
          <p:commandButton id="btnNext" 
                           value="Next" 
                           oncomplete="PF('wizardVar').next()" 
                           process="@this" />      
     </p:tab>
     ...
</p:wizard>
```

And then you can stylish your button as you wish.

Comment: i tried already but i want to increase size of next button without customization like using commandbutton,i want to use build in next button and do changes

Comment: did you try to change the following class ui-wizard-nav-next?

Comment: did you use it like this .ui-wizard .ui-wizard-nav-next {...}? and are you sure you are changing the right CSS